# CSS styles act differently on same browser/different computer

Tags: css, browser

In my office everyone is using IE9.  On most of the computers the CSS renders correctly.  I have text floating to the left and right.  On others, the text does not float or acts odd being positioned below other text. The resolution is the same along with the browser version.  Ontop of this, the border color doesnt apply correctly too.  On one its white, on the rest it has the grey I was expecting to see.  Is there a security setting I'm missing that could stop most of the CSS from working and let the rest work?

Comment: Hit F12 in IE on one of the computers that's acting up. What "Browser Mode"/"Document Mode" is being used?

Comment: By default, IE 8+ is set to use compatibility mode on intranet sites, and it will not show the compatibility view toggle button next to the address bar if this is the case. Go to Tools > Compatibility View Settings, and uncheck all options below the Websites list box. See if that resolves the issue. If it does, you'll want to have your network guys set up your IE installs with these settings as defaults.

Comment: you got it. it was a compatibility mode issue.  I dont know how they turned it on, but that was it. You rock. I feel dumb LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CTRL-F5 to do a cache clear refresh.  You might still be seeing some users previous downloads of reference files.

Comment: Tried that too. Didnt change it.  I would think it was a doctype or anything random, but being the same browser and resolution, I doubt it.

Comment: @Tyler, did you try the IE compatibility mode from above?  that is also a solution.  have you tried to debug the CSS in IE?